# Can I have a 'Favorite tags' button for filtering questions?

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, filtering

Is there a way to show questions specific to your favorite tags?

I think it would be useful to be able to do this. As a suggestion, I would like to have a button with the title 'Favorite tags'. If you click it, only questions with tags related to your favorites will be shown.

Comment: Doesn't the [interesting tab](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) already do this?

Comment: @TravisJ no, that just *highlights* questions in your favourite tags.

Comment: It will show mostly questions whose tags (at least one) belong to the user's favorites though.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3amine%20is%3aq to search for questions in your favourite tags.

Comment: That is useful. The only drawback is that you don't get the `x questions with new activity` push notification which I only get with a bookmarked URL like `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag1%20or%20tag2%20or%20tag3%20`