# New tab on "Questions" page to list questions for all my "Favorite Tags"

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions

I request a new tab on "Questions" page to list questions for all my "Favorite Tags".

I know I can search this using `intags:me is:question`, but a tab will be easy and more accessible.

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251719/5779732) post was requesting the same; but the answers only suggested how to do this through search box.

Following are the questions asking for similar feature.

[List of Questions with in favorite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255651/5779732)
[Filter questions by favorite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256394/5779732)
[Add feature for a new tab that lists questions related to the tags you follow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291927/5779732)
[Can I have a 'Favorite tags' button for filtering questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289589/5779732)
[See only relevant questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289413/5779732)
[Favorite Tags - Remembering of "Tab"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274719/5779732)
[All Questions of all favourite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311801/5779732)